# How to store Vue state between form steps in a cookie for Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, cookies

The scenario is that a user is essentially filling in a multi-step form, we are wanting to save each step in a cookie in case the user loses connection, so their data is not lost between form steps.

We also need that cookie to be sent back to the server to be verified and save any new data in this.

Currently, the server is running a restful API written in Laravel, my understanding is that cookies cannot be sent to a client via rest API?

Is there a way to achieve this via SPA frontend written in Vue, or am I  better just writing server-rendered views and staying from an API solution?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely *can* use cookies with a REST API. Cookies are essentially just HTTP headers, which you can fully control from your SPA and REST API. Although, I would *strongly* consider using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead of juggling this state in a cookie.

As for saving/validating the data on the server-side, typically you would simply perform an HTTP POST to one of your RESTful API endpoints. No reason for cookies to get involved.

Depending on how your multi-step form is modeled on the backend, it could make sense to have the first step create the initial form (`HTTP POST)` and subsequent steps would update that form (`HTTP PUT`). If you need to get the latest saved form data, the client (your SPA) could call the (`HTTP GET`) endpoint.

Here's a general example of how the endpoints could be structured:

```
 - GET:   /api/special-forms/{id} (Returns a the form for the given ID)
 - POST:  /api/special-forms/     (Creates a new form)
 - PUT:   /api/special-forms/{id} (Updates the form matching the given ID)
```